# What is wrong with this Makefile?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I'm trying to learn how to use makefiles in Ubuntu with C (I'm a beginner as you might guess). There is a chapter about this subject in "A Book on C" and they gave a simple example of 3 files: main.c, sum.c, sum.h (without code) and a makefile with this code:

```
sum: main.o sum.o
    gcc –o sum main.o sum.o
main.o: main.c sum.h
    gcc –c main.c 
sum.o: sum.c sum.h
    gcc –c sum.c
```

Now, I am trying to compile this code in eclipse but it doesn't work. I've created a file named makefile with the code above and the 3 files that I mentioned earlier. This is the error that I get:

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Make tells that you: "No rule to make target `all'"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running 'make all', means that you are trying to build a target called 'all', but you haven't defined one.

You need to add in the first line:

```
all: sum
```

BTW, if you'll run 'make' (without an argument), it will build the first target (if there's no 'all' target). That's why I advise you to put the 'all' target as the first one.

Comment: No, if there is an "all" target, it will be built first whether or not there be other targets, regardless to the order.

Comment: @H2CO3: the first target is the one that is built when "make" is called, regardless of whether or not there is an all.

@Jah: I'd also suggest adding: `.PHONY: all` if you're using GNU make.